# Plot matrix data in R (heatmap)

Tags: r, graph

```
require(lattice)
rgb.palette <- colorRampPalette(c("darkgreen","yellow", "red"), space = "rgb")
levelplot(frequency_data, col.regions=rgb.palette(100),xlab="begin",ylab="end")
```

Hi all,I managed to plot my matrix in heatmap format using above command. However I am just wondering is there any way to use area of each square to represent frequency magnitude rather than colour scale? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Functions that ecnode the value of freqency data with area and arrange according to categorical covariates are called mosaic plots. The base function `mosaicplot` is the area-based counterpart of the the color based `image` function. Levelplot (a Lattice function) is actually designed as the lattice counterpart for `contour`. The vcd-package has a lattice-compatible "cotabplot". You will, however, need to edit your question to include the structure of your "frequency_data" object if you want specific directions on how to use that function:

```
 install.packages("vcd")
 require(vcd)
 help(cotabplot)
```